# NetOffice to add a custom form field in outlook new mail window

Tags: outlook

**Problem** : I am not able to find a solution to add a custom form field in outlook new mail window. I am using NetOffice and so far I have implemented to use user accounts from outlook.

**Required guidance** as how to add a custom drop-down button with custom text right under the send mail button.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!
Farhan

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in net office you need to declare a variable to the MAPI folder relevant to the form you want to start altering, and then go through the folder's View collection.  A good start that was done in VBA can be found here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?492714-RESOLVED-Outlook-Programmatically-add-user-defined-field

This link detailed the making of a custom field, and then adding it to the appropriate folder view default form.  You can easily adapt the VBA code in the above link to NetOffice, since it uses the same methods step-through, such as

```
    dim _outlookapplication as Outlook.Application
    dim olNamespace as Outlook._Namespace = _outlookapplication.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    dim olFolder as Outlook.Folder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
    dim olView as Outlook.View
```

Good luck!